# Locus of a point on a variable plane

Tags: vectors, 3d

> A variable plane passes through a fixed point $(a,b,c)$ and meets the
>   coordinate axes in A,B,C.The locus of the point common to the planes
>   through $A,B,C$ parallel to coordinate planes is?

Ok I take a variable plane $l(x-a)+m(y-b)+n(z-x)=d$.I take a point $(h,k)$ whose locus is needed.Next what to do?

Comment: How can a variable line meet the three coordinate axes at once except when it passes through $(0,0,0)$? And if it does pass through the origin, it is no longer variable.

Comment: @AnuragA Sorry...I am in a hurry..so I made some typos...corrected....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the equation of variable plane is $$\frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q}+\frac{z}{r}=1$$

Since it passes through fixed point $(a,b,c)$ we have:$$\frac{a}{p}+\frac{b}{q}+\frac{c}{r}=1$$

The points A, B and C are simply $(p,0,0)$ , $(0,q,0)$ and $(0,0,r)$ respectively.

So the planes parallel to coordinate planes passing though A, B and C are $x=p$ , $y=q$ and $z=r$ respectively.

Their intersection is $(p,q,r)$

I believe the answer is obvious now.